# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController'

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring and I am try to make a application for learning but I am getting problem in Autowiring,I am adding my code. I am working on spring boot.

**logincontroller:**

```
            package com.cloudnexus.spring.controller;

            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

            import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Login;
            import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.User;
            import com.cloudnexus.spring.service.UserService;

            @Controller
            public class LoginController {
                @Autowired
                  UserService userService;

                @RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                  public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                  @ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
                    ModelAndView mav = null;
                    User user = userService.validateUser(login);
                    if (null != user) {
                    mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");
                    mav.addObject("firstname", user.getUsername());
                    } else {
                    mav = new ModelAndView("login");
                    mav.addObject("message", "Username or Password is wrong!!");
                    }
                    return mav;
                  }

            }

            ////
```

**Login POJO:**

```
        package com.cloudnexus.spring.model;

        public class Login {

            private String username;
            private String password;
            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }
            public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
            }
            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
            }



        }
```

**User Pojo :**

```
        package com.cloudnexus.spring.model;

        public class User {

            private String username;
            private String password;
            private int IsActive;
            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }
            public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
            }
            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
            }
            public int getIsActive() {
                return IsActive;
            }
            public void setIsActive(int isActive) {
                IsActive = isActive;
            }

        }
```

**UserDao :**

```
    package com.cloudnexus.spring.dao;

    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Login;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.User;

    public interface UserDao {
        User validateUser(Login login);

    }
```

**UserDaoImpl**

```
    package com.cloudnexus.spring.dao;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Login;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.User;

    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{


        @Autowired
          DataSource datasource;
          @Autowired
          JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        public User validateUser(Login login) {
            String sql = "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "' and password='" + login.getPassword()
            + "'";
            List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
            return users.size() > 0 ? users.get(0) : null;
        }

    }


    class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
          public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("Name"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
            user.setIsActive(rs.getInt("IsActive"));

            return user;
          }
        }
```

**UserService :**

```
    package com.cloudnexus.spring.service;

    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Login;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.User;

    public interface UserService {
        User validateUser(Login login);

    }
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
    package com.cloudnexus.spring.service;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDao;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Login;
    import com.cloudnexus.spring.model.User;

    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
         @Autowired
          public UserDao userDao;
        public User validateUser(Login login) {
            return userDao.validateUser(login);
        }

    }
```

**spring bean configuration file :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.cloudnexus.spring" />
        <context:annotation-config />
        <bean id="userService" class="com.cloudnexus.spring.service.UserServiceImpl">
            <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean name="userDao" class="com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="url" value=";DatabaseName=" />
            <property name="username" value="" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

1. @Autowired to LoginBean loginBean;
2. Created getter setter of LoginBean in Controller class and autowired setters;
3. Created constructor of Controller and autowired, as given in above code;

   **Below is the error which I am getting :**

   ```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao': Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springBeanConfiguration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springBeanConfiguration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao': Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springBeanConfiguration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springBeanConfiguration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
   ```

   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: kindly help me out , Im not able to find the mistake where i have done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jdbcTemplate` bean expects a bean named `datasource`, like you have set-it-up here (in the **`ref=...`** part:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
</bean>
```

But your `datasource` bean does not exist. The reason is because you have defined it as `dataSource` (notice the capital "S") in **`bean id="dataSource"`**

```
  <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value=";DatabaseName=" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

So change this to "datasource" e.g. **`bean id="datasource"`** or change the reference in your `jdbcTemplate` to **`ref="dataSource"`**

Also the `<property name="url" value=";DatabaseName=" />` doesn't look correct, I think you miss the correct `value` here, `";DatabaseName="` looks wrong or incomplete.

**UPDATE**

Since you are using xml spring configuration, the `@Autowired` annotation in your  `UserDaoImpl` and `UserServiceImpl` classes is unnecessary. However, the xml configuration requires that the equivalent getters/setters exist. So change your code as:

In your `UserDaoImpl` you do not need the `dataSource` bean at all, so we are removing it.

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public User validateUser(Login login) {
        String sql = "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "' and password='" + login.getPassword()
                + "'";
        List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
        return users.size() > 0 ? users.get(0) : null;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

You do need however the `jdbcTemplate` bean and in your xml definition you are not setting it, so update also your spring xml file to :

```
<bean name="userDao" class="com.cloudnexus.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

and

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private UserDao userDao;

    public User validateUser(Login login) {
        return userDao.validateUser(login);
    }

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
}
```

Also you have another mistake in the spring xml configuration file. In the `userService` bean definition your are setting it again as a property:

`<property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>`

This is wrong, you should set the `userDao` there. Update it as:

```
<bean id="userService" class="com.cloudnexus.spring.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: i have changed bean id as ="datasource" again im getting error at  userservice bean creation

Comment: ...which is? Please post the error stacktrace. Have you corrected the `<property name="url" value=";DatabaseName=" />` ?

Comment: url value was typing mistake , I have posted the error, Kiindly check and help me out

Comment: If you are using xml configuration like you do, you should not be using annotations like `@Autowired`, this is already done in the spring configuration file. However you should create getters and setters for your properties, I will update my answer to show you

Comment: Please tell me how did you rename the datasource bean? with "S" or "s"? It has its meaning for the getters/setters

Comment: i have changed the ref as ="dataSource"

Comment: A little advice is to choose either spring xml configuration or java configuration with annotations. Using both is confusing.